# Chain Controller Actions in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-mvc, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I have the following two grails Controller. My index action of controller B should call the test action of controller A. After that call index should proceed as it would do without the call to test.

The problem is that index does not renders the view when I call test.

**How can I fix that?**

```
class AController {

  def test() {}

}

class BController {

  def index() {
    // do stuff

    forward controller: 'a', action: 'test'

    // do stuff 

    // render view
  }

}
```

Comment: The way you are expecting the controller to work is not "chaining".

Answer (score 3):

That is not how a controller should work. If those controllers need to share logic they do to much work and that logic should be moved into a service. The service in turn can be used by both controller.